# What is the meaning of concatenation in the case of the cm operator in PDF?

Tags: pdf

I understand that "cm" concatenates two CTMs, however, it's not obvious to me what the specific definition of concatenation is. Reading through to "graphics state operators", in the specification, has not helped me.

Thus far I've looked at a whole bunch of different resources about matrix concatenation. There seems to be a number of different ways concatenation is defined for matrices: some [examples](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html) seem to show it as:

```
[1,2;  concat [5,6;  = [1,2,5,6;
 3,4]          7,8].    3,4,7,8]
```

... however that would seem to break the transform matrices, so I assume that's not it.

Another option is that they just mean matrix addition:

```
[1,2; + [5,6;  = [6 ,8 ;
 3,4]    7,8].    10,12]
```

but I feel, if it were just a matrix addition, they would just call it addition/matrix addition.

my last idea is:

```
[1,2; + [5,6;  = [15,26 ;
 3,4]    7,8].    37,48]
```

but that seems like a bizarre approach, not least because it would have numbers behaving like text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Concatenation here means matrix multiplication on the left side.

Comment: See the PDF Reference. In the 1.7 Reference Transformation Matrices are documented in Section 4.2.3 (page 207). Notice that the CTM is actually a 3x3 matrix where three of the values are fixed. Concatenation (cm) means matrix multiplication. Note that multiplication of matrices is not commutative; the order matters.

Comment: @KenS thank you for your quick reply :) 

I understood the CTM is a 3x3 matrix, but it was unnecessary for my examples to write 3x3 matrices, when 2x2 showed what I meant. I guess I assumed the transformation example given in 4.2.3 was illustrative, because I didn't have the context to know how important it would be. I feel that section probably shouldn't start with "It is not necessary to read this section", given it explains a non-standard use of a specific term.

Thank you for clarifying it for me.

Comment: thank you @mkl for your succinct response :)